# Modulo Power Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

While performing some arithmetic operations, i am stuck at one point.I want to know is it possible to write ($a^b)\%p$ as ($a^{(b\%p)})\%p$?

Comment: No, you need to use the properties given in the dupes. You can find easy counterexamples your claim, e.g. apply it to little Fermat $\,a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, and almost any randomly chosen set of values is a counterexample (for example, take $p=3$ and $a=2$ and $b=4$).

You're right to hope for some kind of reduction shortcut in the exponent. For that you should check out [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and its generalization [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Generalizations).